# Regular expression for following requirement

Tags: python, regex

I am using following regular expression for matching function.

```
FINDFUNC_RE = re.search('^\s*(?:(?:inline|static)\s+){0,2}(?!else|typedef|return)\w+\s+\*?\s*(\w+)\s*\([^0]+\s*?', Line)
```

It correctly matches if line is like this:

```
static int abc(int a)
```

But it does not matches if the line is like this (contains * after return type):

```
static int* abc(int a)
```

What can I do in the regex so that it should match both strings?

Comment: `\w+` won't count on `*`.https://regex101.com/r/6pgKV5/1

Comment: Thanks.It's works.

Answer (score 0):

```
(static|inline)\s+int(\s*\*)*\s+[a-zA-Z]\w*\(.*\)
```

gives you an optional star as pointer